# Right align in eqnarray

Tags: equations, align

I have a MWE where I use `eqnarray` for multiline equations. I want to right align those two `text`, but `\hfill` is not working here.

I think I may use `align`, but here just want to know how to do it with `eqnarray`.

```
\documentclass[]{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Example}
\begin{eqnarray*}
A &=& B + C \hfill (\Leftarrow \text{from Theorem 1}) \\
  &=& D + E \hfill (\Leftarrow \text{from Corollary 2}) \\
  &=& F 
\end{eqnarray*}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Try an `&&` after `C` and `E`. For example `C && (\Leftarrow \text{from Theorem 1})`

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/196/eqnarray-vs-align

Comment: @Jubobs --- Beamer has some issues with amsmath environments; see page 78 of the [Beamer manual](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/beamer) for details.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this with `align`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[]{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Example}
\begin{align*}
A &= B + C && (\Leftarrow \text{from Theorem 1}) \\
  &= D + E && (\Leftarrow \text{from Corollary 2}) \\
  &= F &&
\end{align*}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Or alternatively exploiting the `\tag{<content>}` command:

[image]

```
\documentclass[]{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Example}
\begin{align}
A &= B + C  \tag{$\Leftarrow$ from Theorem 1} \\
  &= D + E  \tag{$\Leftarrow$ from Corollary 2} \\
  &= F \notag
\end{align}
\end{frame}
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend the `\tag` method.

Comment: @egreg The OP did not specify any specific technique so I opted with what I quickly had in my mind. Please do edit my question and explain why the `\tag` is not advisable or post a comment here so that I can amend my answer.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a solution that uses the `IEEEeqnarray` environment of the [IEEEtrantools](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/IEEEtran/tools) package. This package uses syntax that's very similar to that of the (severely deprecated!) `eqnarray` environment while (i) avoiding all of the shortcomings of the `eqnarray` environment and (ii) providing some nifty enhancements, such as being able to place text (via the "x" column specifier) on the far-right-hand end of a row. (
The full documentation of the `IEEEeqnarray` environment may be found in Appendix F of the article "[How to Use the IEEEtran LATEX Class](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/IEEEtran/IEEEtran_HOWTO.pdf)" by Michael Shell.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{IEEEtrantools}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t] % "[t]" just for this example
\frametitle{Example}
\begin{IEEEeqnarray*}{+rCl+x*}
A &=& B + C \hfill &($\Leftarrow$ from Theorem 1) \\
  &=& D + E \hfill &($\Leftarrow$ from Corollary 2) \\
  &=& F 
\end{IEEEeqnarray*}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

---

For `beamer` users, a major advantage of using the `IEEEeqnarray` environment rather than, say, the math environments of the `amsmath` package is that it's straightforward to create overlays using the `\visible<...>{...}` way. For instance, the following setup

```
\begin{IEEEeqnarray*}{+rCl+x*}
             A &=& B + C \hfill &($\Leftarrow$ from Theorem 1) \\
\visible<2->{  &=& D + E \hfill &($\Leftarrow$ from Corollary 2)} \\
\visible<3>{   &=& F }
\end{IEEEeqnarray*}
```

will show the first line on all three overlays, the second line from the second overlay onwards, and the third line only on the third (and last) overlay.